# Facing the error in deploying React web app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I tried to deploy my React web app to heroku via my github repository but I get the following error, **!     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.** I crawled all over the internet in the search of the solution, but I didn't find any. The complete log that I have got is as follows,

```
-----> Using buildpack: mars/create-react-app
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.58 does not satisfy @material-ui/lab@*
       npm ERR! 
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Y9WIv/_logs/2021-05-15T16_32_16_496Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

Any idea as to where am going wrong? Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: The error indicated package.json and package-lock.json are not in sync. you can remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, run `npm install` and push the updated `package-lock.json` back to see if the build is still prompting error.

Comment: @MicFung I have done this and am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you have both `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` at the same time?

Comment: @MicFung Nope, I only have `package-lock.json`

Comment: Can you check the `package.json` if the `@material-ui/lab` is `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58"` or `"@material-ui/lab": "*"`

Comment: If you have `"@material-ui/lab": "*"`, please change it to `"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58"` and npm install again